# Make a bar graph of 2 variables based on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph of two variables but without success. My goal is to to create a bar graph where the Events1 And Events2 appear along in order to be easier to compare the "Name" (two bars for each Name). My code below generates two graphs wrongly. Can you point me out to the correct way of doing this?Thanks.

My df is:

```
         Name  Events1 Events2
0  Accounting        3       3
1   Reporting        1       4
2     Finance        1      13
3       Audit        1      17
4    Template        2      40
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df[['Events1','Events2']].plot(kind='bar', title ="test", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Name", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Number", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass two Y-axis values

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'Name', y = ['Events1', 'Events2'], rot = 40)
```

If you wish to annotate the bars, try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.bar(x = 'Name', y = ['Events1', 'Events2'], rot = 40, ax = ax)
for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea how could have the "Name" labels inside the bars? I am reading the documentation but can't figure it.

Comment: Sorry, i meant  the words Audit, Finance, etc written inside the bars . To not take space from the image bottom.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Vaishali

Answer (score 3):

Use `set_index`

```
In [3596]: df.set_index('Name').plot.bar()
Out[3596]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2954d208>
```

[image]

---

```
In [3595]: df.set_index('Name')
Out[3595]:
            Events1  Events2
Name
Accounting        3        3
Reporting         1        4
Finance           1       13
Audit             1       17
Template          2       40
```